# You have already activated rack 1.0.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.1. - Passenger + Rails 3

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, rack

I am trying to get Passenger working on my local OSX machine as I need to have non-port based urls for testing a post-back from a payment gateway, and I do not want to develop on the server!

I get the error: "You have already activated rack 1.0.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.1." when trying to load the site via Passenger (using the Passenger PrefPane in OSX).

It was wokring fine previously with "rails server" (WEbrick).

I got an error from Passenger about mysql - I am using mysql2 - so I tried removing 'mysql' which was in my Gemfile and leaving mysql2. This seemed to solve that issue, but since then I have been stuck on this Rack issue.

(on a side note also having trouble installing mysql via bundle..)

I saw that newer versions of Passenger don't have this problem. Installed the lastest but no joy (does it matter if I use the PrefPane?)

I feel like I might be about to get my system into a mess so looking for some advice on this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because Phusion Passenger tries to load (the latest version of) Rack after which your app tries to load a specific, different version of Rack. Make sure you activate your bundle from config/setup_load_paths.rb, which is called before Phusion Passenger loads Rack.

Comment: Ok - I created config/setup_load_paths.rb, however it seems to be being ignored... I added "raise RuntimeError" at the top to make sure.

Comment: My config/setup_load_paths.rb looks like this:

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'bundler/setup'

Comment: Also - I am using passenger version 3

Comment: I managed to get it working how I need by running "rails server -p 80", and adding the local domain into /etc/hosts .. not ideal but it works for now. Thanks